# Python: Simple Web Crawler using BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup

I have been following TheNewBoston's Python 3.4 tutorials that use Pycharm, and am currently on the tutorial on how to create a web crawler. I Simply want to download all of XKCD's Comics. Using the archive that seemed very easy. Here is [my code](http://pastebin.com/eNTPqGQn), followed by [TheNewBoston](http://pastebin.com/EscfdDV2)'s.
Whenever I run the code, nothing happens. It runs through and says, "Process finished with exit code 0" Where did I screw up?

TheNewBoston's Tutorial is a little dated, and the website used for the crawl has changed domains. I will comment the part of the video that seems to matter.

My code:

```
mport requests
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def download_img(image_url, page):
    name = str(page) + ".jpg"
    request.urlretrieve(image_url, name)


def xkcd_spirder(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = r'http://xkcd.com/' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll('div', {'img': 'src'}):
            href = link.get('href')
            print(href)
            download_img(href, page)
        page += 1

xkcd_spirder(5)
```

Comment: The Video Tutorial. https://youtu.be/sVNJOiTBi_8?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAcbMi1sH6oAMk4JHw91mC_

Comment: You haven't explained what's going wrong, or asked a question...?  Still, I'm gonna guess that you get an error in `download_img` saying `name 'page' is undefined` - because `page` only exists inside `xkcd_spirder` and you can't use it from somewhere else. You need to pass it into `download_img` as a parameter.

Comment: I just tried what I assume you mean. Still very new. Here is the new code. Same problem as before. Also edited original post to actually have my problem. got a little to excited there, haha. http://pastebin.com/nv6X7S0M

Answer (score 1):

The *comic* is in the div with the id *comic*, you just need to pull the *src* from *img* inside that div then join it to the *base* url and finally request the content and write, I use the *basename* as the name to save the file under.

I also replaced your while with a range loop and did all the http requests just using requests:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from os import path
from urllib.parse import urljoin # python2 -> from urlparse import urljoin 


def download_img(image_url, base):
     # path.basename(image_url) 
    #  http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/tree_cropped_(1).jpg -> tree_cropped_(1).jpg -
    with open(path.basename(image_url), "wb") as f:
        # image_url is a releative path, we have to join to the base 
        f.write(requests.get(urljoin(base,image_url)).content)


def xkcd_spirder(max_pages):
    base = "http://xkcd.com/"
    for page in range(1, max_pages + 1):
        url = base + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        # we only want one image
        img = soup.select_one("#comic img") # or .find('div',id= 'comic').img
        download_img(img["src"], base)

xkcd_spirder(5)
```

Once you run the code you will see we get the first five comics.